# MockWebServer - ConnectException: Failed to connect to

Tags: android, kotlin, mockwebserver

When I start my test I get connect exception and I have no idea why.

I found some code others authors and compare code and i didn't find anything wrong. I tried to change ports or remove it and it didn't help me.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class RideFragmentTest {

@get:Rule
    val activityRule: ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)
    private val mockWebServer = MockWebServer()
    private val PORT = 8607

@Before
    fun init() {
        mockWebServer.start(PORT)
        routeToFragment()
    }

@After
    fun finish() {
        mockWebServer.shutdown()
    }

@Test
    fun someTest() {
        val dispatcher = object : Dispatcher() {
            @Throws(InterruptedException::class)
            override fun dispatch(request: RecordedRequest): MockResponse {
                when (request.path) {
                    "/something/current" -> {
                        val jsonBody = asset(activityRule.activity, "something.json")
                        return MockResponse().setResponseCode(200).setBody(jsonBody)
                    }
                    "/something/save" -> {
                        return MockResponse().setResponseCode(200)
                    }
                }
                return MockResponse().setResponseCode(404)
            }
        }
        mockWebServer.dispatcher = dispatcher

        assertDisplayed(..., ...)
    }
}
```

```
D/OkHttp: --> GET http://127.0.0.1:8607/something/current
D/OkHttp: --> END GET
HTTP FAILED: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:8607
```

I didn't find any strange logs.

Comment: I'm not certain but try to remove the port

Comment: @GilGoldzweig thank you for your answer. I tried it and it didn't help to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my question.

My code should be like this:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class RideFragmentTest {

private val fragment = RideFragment.newInstance()

@get:Rule
    val activityRule: ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)
    private val mockWebServer = MockWebServer()
    private val PORT = 8607

@Before
    fun init() {
        mockWebServer.start(PORT)
    }

@After
    fun finish() {
        mockWebServer.shutdown()
    }

@Test
    fun someTest() {
        val dispatcher = code above..
        mockWebServer.dispatcher = dispatcher
        routeToFragment()

        assertDisplayed(..., ...)
    }

    private fun routeToFragment() = activityRule
       .activity
       .supportFragmentManager
       .beginTransaction()
       .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
       .commit()
}
```

i.e. I had to route my fragment after setting dispatcher because mockwebserver had no time for initialization otherwise(i understand so).

Comment: could you please give a more detailed answer? What's the method `routeToFragment()`?

Comment: It's just routing between fragments. I'll try to find this part of the code

Comment: What do you mean by "routing between fragments". Since this is the key to your solution, I think you explain it in more detail.

Comment: @ADroid I added info about routeToFragment() method. I hope you will understand this code.